# How do I keep bone relationships visible at all times?

Tags: armature

I can only see bone relationships when I select a single bone, but I want to see all the bone relationships without selecting all of the bones.

blender 2.7 doesn't have this problem.

Comment: How do you see the relationship in Blender 2.7? In Blender 2.8+ you can see it in the outliner.

Comment: What do you mean by "bone relationships"? Some of us can't remember what Blender 2.7 looked like, let alone how the relationships were shown! If you mean relationship lines in the viewport, you can enable them in the Viewport Overlays menu under Objects > Relationship Lines, otherwise see @Blunder's answer.

Comment: maybe this? https://blendermarket.com/products/visualize-bone-parents